# Running at most n Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a CPU intensive application, which can be written in Java. The application consists of few jobs (threads) that run independently.

If I start all the threads at once, the system will be overloaded. How could I start at most n threads at once, and when one thread finishes then a new one is started? By limiting the number of threads running at once, I intend to leave some other processors/cores available for other tasks.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should formulate your threads' tasks as `Runnable`s or `Callable`s and then submit them to a fixed thread pool executor. The executor will manage a pool of worker threads and run your tasks from an internal queue on those threads.

See [Executors#newFixedThreadPool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) for a factory method that creates the type of executor you want.

Answer (score 7):

Use a fixed size executor pool.

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

Comment: Thanks. The resource http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/executorservice shows a clear example.